# Display string variables in a Toast

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, toast, string-concatenation

I wanna display the information of 7 `EditText` in a `Toast` so I put the edit texts information in 7 string variables but I don't know how.
  Here is what I written:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        EditText ed1;
        EditText ed2;
        EditText ed3;
        EditText ed4;
        EditText ed5;
        EditText ed6;
        EditText ed7;
        Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            showinfo();
        }

        private void showinfo() {
            ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            ed2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            ed3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            ed4= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            ed5= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            ed6= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            ed7= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ///////
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str1 = ed1.getText().toString();
                    String str2 = ed2.getText().toString(); 
                    String str3 = ed3.getText().toString(); 
                    String str4 = ed4.getText().toString(); 
                    String str5 = ed5.getText().toString(); 
                    String str6 = ed6.getText().toString(); 
                    String str7 = ed7.getText().toString();
                    ////////////
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I display all the string variables in `Toast`?

Comment: Are you looking for `Concatination`? Just use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show all content of `EditText` in one `Toast`, then just use concatenation

```
String concatenatedText = str1 + str2 + str3 + ...
```

or `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1);
sb.append(str2);
sb.append(str3);
String concatenatedText = sb.toString();
```

and simply pass the result as second argument, as below:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, concatenatedText, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) suggest

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

you could for sure do something like:

Context context = getApplicationContext();
String text = str1 + str2 + str3 + ...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1);
sb.append(str2);
sb.append(str3);
String finalMsgText = sb.toString();

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, finalMsgText , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

the point with that way to go is that

when 
 str1 = "Hello";
 str2 = "Xoce";
 str3 = "How are you?";

then the msg in the toast will be like:

> "HelloXoceHow are you?";

so everything together makes no sence for the app user...

## Solution:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1).append(", ");;
sb.append(str2).append(", ");;
sb.append(str3);
String finalMsgText = sb.toString();

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, finalMsgText , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```